# Drop rows containing "-" in a column

Tags: pandas, drop

how can i drop all the rows which containing "-" in a column?

[image]

I have tried:

```
df1['Refl'] = df1['Refl'].str.replace('-', 'NaN').astype(int)
```

but got followirng error: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Answer (score 2):

You find the index of the rows with '-' and drop them too.

```
idx = df1[df1['Ref1'] == '-'].index
df1.drop(idx , inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df1 = df1[~df1['Refl'].eq('-')]
```

Another solution:

```
df1['Refl'] = df1['Refl'].replace('-': np.nan)
df1 = df1.dropna(subset='Refl')
```